# jQuery; add code and text into element

Tags: jquery, html

So I have an array that's supposed to have 3 entries.

Entry 1:

```
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
<i>"Lorem Ipsum."</i><br><br>
<b>Jane Doe</b>
```

Entry 2:

```
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
<i>"Ipsum Lorem"</i><br><br>
<b>John Smith</b>
```

I have a function that's supposed to randomly pick one entry from the array. But the question is; how can I have the HTML code **and** text in an array entry? It just gets messed up with the quotation marks.

End point is supposed to be; function randomly picks out one entry to later *append* the entry to another element.

This is the code picking a random entry if you want to see it:

```
var chosen = reviews[Math.floor(Math.random() * reviews.length)];
```

`reviews` is the variable name for the array.

Comment: why don't you create jquery element and add to array ?

Comment: As I can see your html is common and only value are changed so why do you want to keep entire html elements in array ? I would suggest that you can simply keep values in array and bind randomly picked value with the html elements and display..

Comment: @Deepak the HTML is sort of changed between the two. On the first; the last `<i>` class is different from the second entry. How can I bind the html to the entries..? I thought of that aswell but I couldn't figure out a way to actually do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your trouble? Use single and double quotes.

```js
var reviews=[];
// Entry 1
reviews.push(
    '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>' +
    '<i>"Lorem Ipsum."</i><br><br>' +
    '<b>Jane Doe</b>'
);
// Entry 2
reviews.push(
    '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>' +
    '<i>"Ipsum Lorem"</i><br><br>' +
    '<b>John Smith</b>'
);
var chosen = reviews[Math.floor(Math.random() * reviews.length)];
document.getElementById('MyContainer').innerHTML = chosen;
```

```html
<p id="MyContainer"></p>
```

Comment: Don't know why, but it didn't work for me.. Now it does work. I'm so confused

Comment: It's working for me now! Realized that it didn't function because I had the entries on several rows and only one set of quotation marks for the whole entry.. I blame my lack of sleep